# Replace each character of white space at the end of each line with '_'

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed

I'm wanting to replace each character of white space at the end of each line with '_'. I found a similar question and answer for leading whitespace. But have failed to reconstruct it for trailing whitespace. Here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222281/replace-leading-whitespace-with-sed-or-similar

If anyone can think of a quicker or better way, that would also be great. I also appreciate good explanations, as that way I learn quicker :)

```
Input:
foo bar
 foo bar oof
  line 3a  
  line fo a

Output:
foo bar_____
 foo bar oof
  line 3a___
  line fo a_
```

Comment: If I cut and paste your sample input, the "foo bar" line has no trailing whitespace. Do you want to add some so all the lines are the same length?

Comment: yes, sorry, whitespace should be there and replaced as per the output example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and gensub():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(.*[^ ])(.*)/,a){$0=a[1] gensub(/ /,"_","g",a[2])} 1' file
foo bar_____
 foo bar oof
  line 3a___
  line fo a_
```

With any awk:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/ +$/){tail=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); gsub(/ /,"_",tail); $0=substr($0,1,RSTART-1) tail} 1' file
foo bar_____
 foo bar oof
  line 3a___
  line fo a_
```

To replace leading blanks too by tweaking the above gawk solution:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/^( *)(.*[^ ])(.*)/,a){$0=gensub(/ /,"_","g",a[1]) a[2] gensub(/ /,"_","g",a[3])} 1' file
foo bar_____
_foo bar oof
__line 3a___
__line fo a_
```

Comment: The OP is apparently trying to print lines that all line up on the right side so I doubt if they want a tab to be replaced with a single `_` but their input doesn't contain any tabs so we're guessing. ln any case, why not post that as an answer as it's a reasonable approach?

Comment: I don't think posting different awk scripts as comments under one answer is as useful to the community as posting them as different answers but it's every posters prerogative I suppose.

Comment: @mosvy . I switched out the tab for space and that awk command is so much faster than the sed command. Because of this I also tried using it for the leading spaces, editing sections I thought I understood to make it work for leading.... I failed miserably. Could you explain how to implement this for leading spaces too?

Comment: @mosvy here's another good reason to post your own answer - so I don't get messages in my Inbox when people try to talk to you about your answer as I did just now (and presumably will get alerted when you respond to them too). It'd also be nice if the OP could accept your answer if they like, which they can't do if it's buried in a list of comments.

Comment: Ed, I tried yours too, equally as fast, had I seen it before the sed post I would have accepted it as the answer. I also can't re-work yours to also doing the leading spaces. I wish I was better with awk! so any explanation/breakdown of your answer would really help me learn.

Comment: You CAN unaccept answers and accept others if you like. I just tweaked my answer to also replace leading blanks with underscores.

Comment: I didn't know that. Well as the sed command wasn't practical time wise for the file size I'm dealing with, this really is a far more suitable answer, so I'm going to switch it.

Comment: @Giles See my answer for leading and leading+trailing spaces. Notice that EdMorton's solution doesn't work with lines which are just spaces; but, since my observations are not taken well, I'll stop posting "nitpicking" comments on his answers.

Comment: @mosvy wrt `my observations are not taken well1` - I'm sorry you feel that way, what did I say to give you that impression? My response to your first comment here was "why not post that as an answer as it's a reasonable approach?" and the last time before this that I remember commenting on something you posted that mentioned me [I said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk#comment107352169_60676023) "That's a nice FPAT, ... you should suggest the gawk folks update their FPAT documentation to use it".

Answer (score 9):

With GNU sed, replacing all spaces at eol by underscore:

```
sed ':x;s/ \( *\)$/_\1/;tx'
```

Comment: Probably since Oracle took it over.

Comment: Was meant to be funny.   What gives "sed ':x s/ \\( *\\)$/_\1/;tx'" on Solaris?  But even with the --posix parameter, my original solution still works.

Comment: I read you LOUD and CLEAR.

Answer (score 4):

More efficient to use perl:

```
perl -lpe 's/(\s+)$/"_" x length($1)/e' input.txt
```

which only has to do one substitution per line with trailing whitespace, instead of looping.

Comment: But needs loading a 3Mb executable vs. a 120kb one.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille modern systems (ie newer > 198x) are using on-demand loading and a unified buffer cache.

Answer (score 2):

#### With awk

```
awk -F '[ \t]+$' 'NF>1{t=substr($0,length($1)+1);gsub(/./,"_",t); $0=$1 t} 1'
```

This also handles a mixture of **trailing** tabs and spaces. The field separator (`-F`, `FS`) can be easily adjusted to only match spaces or also match other kind of invisible characters, provided that it's kept anchored at the end with `$`.

To make that work for **leading** blanks, everything should be mirrored not just `$` to `^`:

```
awk -F '^[ \t]+' 'NF>1{h=substr($0,1,length()-length($2));gsub(/./,"_",h); $0=h $2} 1'
```

To make it work for **both leading and trailing** blanks, the logic should be inverted; set the field separator to a pattern *not* matching leading and trailing blanks:

```
awk -F '[^ \t](.*[^ \t]|$)' '{s=$0; h=gsub(/./,"_",$1); t=gsub(/./,"_",$2); print $1 substr(s,h+1, length(s)-h-t) $2}'
```

Or the same with adjustable pattern:

```
awk -v ns='[^ \t]' 'BEGIN{FS=ns"(.*"ns"|$)"}{s=$0; h=gsub(/./,"_",$1); t=gsub(/./,"_",$2); print $1 substr(s,h+1, length(s)-h-t) $2}'
```

Different from [@EdMorton's solutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/575450/308316), these handle correctly lines which contain only spaces and will work with any implementation of awk, not just GNU awk (gawk): eg. with mawk or bwk ("original-awk"), which are both much faster than gawk. But even when used with gawk, the last solution will be almost twice as fast as @EdMorton's.

#### With sed

With sed, the only solution I can think of is to substitute repeatedly in a loop; if there are many trailing spaces and long lines, this can get slow fast:

```
sed -e :x -e 's/ \( *\)$/_\1/;tx'
```

Notice that `sed ':x;s/ \( *\)$/_\1/;tx'` is not [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) sed; `:label` is not one of the commands which can be terminated by a `;`:

> Editing commands **other than** `{...}`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `i`, `r`, `t`, `w`, **`:`**, and `#` can be followed by a `<semicolon>`, optional `<blank>` characters, and another editing command.

#### With perl

Here is an alternate perl solution, which is NOT really an improvement upon the existing [perl answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/575444/308316), but which, since it doesn't use the `e` flag of `s///`, could be theoretically adapted to some other tool providing a sed-like `s///` and perl/pcre-like zero-width assertions in its regexes:

```
perl -ple 's/\s(?=\s*$)/_/g'
```

Comment: I've never seen a fancy awk field separator like that before. Cool!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to *add* whitespace to even out the lines:

```bsh
$ cat -A file
foo bar$
 foo bar oof$
  line 3a  $
  line fo a$
```

Lines are not even

```bsh
perl -MList::Util=max -lne '
    push @lines, $_
}
END {
    $wid = max map {length} @lines;
    for $line (@lines) {
        $padded = sprintf "%-*s", $wid, $line;
        $padded =~ s/(\s+)$/"_" x length($1)/e;
        print $padded
    }
' file
```

```
foo bar_____
 foo bar oof
  line 3a___
  line fo a_
```

Comment: You can also use `pack "A$length", $line` instead of `sprintf`. Example: `perl -MList::Util=max -e '$p="_"x($l=max map{s/\s*$//;length}@l=<>); print map
{pack"A$l a",$_.$p,"\n"}@l'`

Comment: or working like your example when the longest line also had trailing spaces: `perl -MList::Util=max -le '$p="_"x($l=max map{chomp;length}@l=<>); print for map {pack"A$l",s/\s+$//r.$p}@l'`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via the following simple methods also :

Perl splits on nonwhitespace and perform the transliteration of space to underscore on the last field. Then print all fields.

```
$ perl -F'(\S+)'  -lane '
    $F[-1] =~ tr/ /_/ if @F;
    print @F;
' file
```

Using GNU sed we perform the equivalent of lookahead:

```
$ sed -re '
    y/ /\n/
    :loop
      s/\n(\S| )/ \1/
    tloop
    y/\n/_/
' file
```

This will work posixly (change \S to [^[:space:]])

```
$ sed -e '
    h;s/\s*$//;x;s/.*\S//
    y/ /_/;x;G;s/\n//
' file
```

This method will work only in gnu sed as it makes use of s///e extended flag.

```
$ sed -re '
    s/(.*\S)(.*)/echo "\1""$(echo "\2" | tr " " _)"/e
' file
```

Comment: Your perl will choke on empty lines with `Modification of non-creatable array value attempted`. You sed `s///e` (the last) will probably take an hour to finish on an input that the perl will handle in 1 or 2 seconds ;-)

Comment: It is no big deal, just make the tranliteration conditional. Well the OP mentioned no need for speed in his query.

Comment: 1. It's a bug. 2. Should they mention it? The `sed s///e` is not twice, or thrice, or ten times slower, but 3000 times slower (and that assuming a multicore system and an OS with very fast process creation, like Linux -- otherwise it can easily get 30000 or 100000 times slower).

Comment: Hello, we are not making production code here. The OP gave a data we tried on it. If you want to nitpick then ask the Op to provide comprehensive input.

Comment: 1. Don't royal-we me. 2. Welcome to my kill-list.